# Replace Text into image tag using comma separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

code is using jquery and i am trying change text into image tag with comma separator so every word i need image tag. in that case when image is replaced 30 Degree Wash is gone.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.pa_wash .attribute-value:contains("iron")').html('<img src="edit.png"/>');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <li class="pa_wash">
            <span class="attribute-label">Wash :  </span>
            <span class="attribute-value">30 Degree Wash, iron</span>
        </li>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.pa_wash .attribute-value:contains("iron")').html(function () {
    return this.innerHTML
    .replace("iron", '<img src="edit_0.png"/>')
    .replace("30 Degree Wash", '<img src="edit_1.png"/>');
  });
});
```

You need to replace the word `iron` with your image and then set the `html` again.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/k8wr0yqa/1/)

Comment: thanks for reply now image tag just replace iron word, can you help me little more to "30 Degree Wash" replace also another image tag

Comment: <span class="attribute-value">30 Degree Wash, iron</span> that span have two values, you explain above about iron how to change but i need image tag also for 30 Degree Wash

Comment: Check updated answer. please consider upvoting and marking it as correcr answer.